# Free available parallel (MPI) debugger for Linux?

Tags: c++, debugging, parallel-processing, mpi

Is there a non-commerical/free available Linux tool for debugging of MPI parallelized C++ code? Something like Allinea DDT or TotalView? I know the tricks how to make use of gdb to attach to parallel running codes. But I find them tedious just to make some fast debugging. So is there any GUI based tool (maybe based on gdb) that directly supports for parallel debugging?

Comment: If your development machine has the specs of a small supercomputer so that it can run Eclipse, then you can try the [Eclipse Parallel Tools Platform](http://www.eclipse.org/ptp/).

Comment: Seems to be worth to give it a try ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eclipse PTP (http://www.eclipse.org/ptp/) is fine for this purpose

Answer (score 2):

I use openmpi and ddd (it's GUI for gdb):

mpirun -np 4 ddd my_program

After that, 4 windows appear, each process in its own window.
If your program has to start with command line arguments, they are given in ddd windows and
every command has to be done in every window. It's not so convenient, but it works.

Comment: This could be useful, if you have only 4 process. But even with a small number of 16 processes, this becomes somehow confusing. And it does not supports mpi subcomms.

Answer (score 1):

Depending of the MPI implementation that you are using, you can run

```
mpirun --gdb
```

Or

```
mpirun -gdb -n 4 ./testc
```

Check [Intel's](https://software.intel.com/en-us/mpi-developer-guide-linux-debugging-1) documentation for more details.

Comment: Link is dead at the time of this comment.

Comment: They probably have a newer version and killed this older version. I added Intel's documentation now